# Unexpected token, expected ...

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting the following error in react

> Unexpected token, expected ... (16:6)

```
 return (
  15 |   <div className={classes.BuildControls}
16 |     { controls.map(el =>(<BuildControl key={el.label} label={el.label} />))}
     |       ^
  17 |   </div>
  18 |  )
  19 | };
```

Here is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import Classes from './build-controls.css';
import BuildControl from './build-control-r/build-control.js';

const controls = [
  { label: "Salad", type:"salad"  },
  { label: "Cheese", type:"cheese" },
  { label: "Meat", type:"meat" },
  { label: "bacon", type:"bacon" }
]


const buildControls = (props) => {
  return (
  <div className={classes.BuildControls}
    { controls.map(el =>(<BuildControl key={el.label} label={el.label} />))}
  </div>
 )
};

export default buildControls;
```

**[Question]** : Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong? Do let me know if i need to share something else as well

Comment: You did not close your div after className. put `>` in opening div block

Comment: That works, Thanks a lot Kishan

Comment: @KishanMundha Since you solved this initially, if you add this as an answer, I would gladly mark this as answered :)

Comment: I have add answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please close element

```
const buildControls = (props) => {
  return (
  <div className={classes.BuildControls}> // Need to close bracket
    { controls.map(el =>(<BuildControl key={el.label} label={el.label} />))}
  </div>
 )
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close the first div.

```
import React from 'react';
import Classes from './build-controls.css';
import BuildControl from './build-control-r/build-control.js';

const controls = [
  { label: "Salad", type:"salad"  },
  { label: "Cheese", type:"cheese" },
  { label: "Meat", type:"meat" },
  { label: "bacon", type:"bacon" }
]


const buildControls = (props) => {
  return (
  <div className={classes.BuildControls}>  //This one right arrow
    { controls.map(el =>(<BuildControl key={el.label} label={el.label} />)) }
  </div>
)
};

export default buildControls;
```